# Fast searching approach in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, binary-search-tree

[image]

The above searching I want with minimum number of code and with best serach performance.

I want to generate an array from this above array by putting logic like:
ALL "EMA" key values of array should not be allowed to match with "JACKSON" key values. **Similarly** all "JACKSON" key values of the same array are not allowed to fall in any value of "EMA" key. So the resulting array would be like shown below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [EMA] => A
            [JACKSON] => B
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [EMA] => D
            [JACKSON] => E
        )
)
```

I want to know the best approach with lesser code to achieve this. The method I have used seems so lengthy. I want a shorter and robust approach.

Comment: You might want to show us what you've got so far. Specially since you want a "shorter" approach. Hard to know what's shorter than unknown.

Comment: The approach which I have used is: create one array with all keys of "EMA" like Array[EMA](A,B,D,F). Second array of all keys = "JACKSON". Now used foreach loop and checked each key value falls in Array[EMA](A,B,D,F) or any other.

Comment: Add your actual code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a solution:

```
$emas = array();
$jacksons = array();
foreach($array as $element){
    $emas[] = $element['EMA'];
    $jacksons[] = $element['JACKSON'];
}
//array_intersect returns the common values in the arrays as an array
if(!empty(array_intersect($emas, $jacksons))){
    echo 'array is invalid!';
}
```